# strpos() function on mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

i have the code fetching the information from the MySQL database in PHP and then i want to compare $username variable with those information with strpos() function...but it doesn't work....
what can i do?

```
 $username = $_GET['username'];
 $connection = new DB_Database();
 $res = $connection->Select();
 if ($res) {
 $output = "";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    if (strpos((string)$row['username'], $username)) {
        $output.=" " . $row["username"] . " ";
    } 

echo $output;
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this comparison as part of the SQL query to begin with? Also, are you simply forgetting the difference between `== 0` and `=== false`, as described on the manual page for `strpos`?

Answer (score 1):

I 'm not sure why you are using `strpos` instead of a straight comparison with `==`, but this code would not work correctly if `$row['username'] == $username`.

The reason is that in this case `strpos` would return `0`, which evaluates to `false` -- see the giant red warning on the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: i want to find something like "mik" in "mikes peters". I have the database has a row named "username" i want to search the names with a string in it.just this is the reason for using strpos()

Comment: @PouyanIzadi: In that case `strpos(...) !== false` would work. But this would be a really bad way to implement search -- move the filtering logic into your SQL instead with something like `WHERE username LIKE %:param%`.